# How to make modal close on click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used this JavaScript below:

```js
$('body').click(function() {
  if (!$(this.target).is('#popUpForm')) {
    $(".modalDialog").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div class="modalClose">
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close-circle" style="color:white; text-decoration:none; font-size:14px;"></a>
      <div id="signup-header">
        <h4>Request a brochure, with a free demo</h4>
        <h5>Please Fill in the form below: </h5>
      </div>

      <form id="popUpForm" class="tryMeForm" name="" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);" method="post" action="">
        <div class="InputGroup">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="First Name*" />
        </div>
        <div class="InputGroup">
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name*" />
        </div>
        <div class="InputGroup">
          <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="" placeholder="Email Address*" />
        </div>
        <div class="InputGroup">
          <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" value="" placeholder="Phone Number*" />
        </div>
        <div class="InputGroup">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="" placeholder="How we can help?"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
          <input class="button_submit1 button-primary button1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This allows me to close the modal when clicking outside of it. However, it closes even when I click inside as well. How can I make it close only on outside and the close button, but not inside, so the users can still enter their details?

Comment: you have to check the parent node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seemed to be the code that worked out for me in the end:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#openModal')) {
        $('#openModal').fadeOut(500);
    }

});

$("#modalNo").click(function () {
    $("#openModal").fadeOut(500);


});
$(".close").click(function () {
    $("#openModal").fadeOut(500);
});
$(".close-circle").click(function () {
    $("#openModal").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 27):

Use the parent node `#openModal` (container) instead of `#popUpForm` (form) :

```
$('body').click(function (event) 
{
   if(!$(event.target).closest('#openModal').length && !$(event.target).is('#openModal')) {
     $(".modalDialog").hide();
   }     
});
```

Comment: this will work if the length of the children of element `#openModal` is exactly one. It is actually a little more complicated than just checking the `e.target`

Comment: Thanks @self for your intervention, you could use `closest()` to cover the part of children/parent... (Updating my answer).

Comment: I found out that the modal plugin I use, developed by a potato, was using `e.stopPropagation()` to achieve the same goal, which inevitably prevented events being fired for anything inside of the modal! I used your solution to fix what the potato coded.

Answer (score 18):

Adding to this for future readers.

Another way to dismiss the modal when clicking outside involved taking advantage of the bubbling nature of the javascript events.

In a typical modal HTML structure

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
    -- Site content here
  </div>
  <div id="modal-root">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

clicking on `.modal` will cause the click event to propagate like this `.modal -> #modal-root -> body` while clicking outside the modal will only go through `#modal-root -> body`.

Since we can stop the propagation of click events completely, and if that does not interfere with any other code, we only need to listen for click events in both `.modal` and `#modal-root`. A "modal-root" click will dismiss the modal, and a "modal" click will stop propagating the click event so never reaches the "modal-root".

For extra clarity, here's the code working in codepen.io: https://codepen.io/nbalaguer/pen/PVbEjm

Comment: It is nice approach, though things get complicated if you have some clickable elements in the model (send button, link to terms and conditions etc.).

Comment: @Kout it still works because clicks on inner elements are not influenced if you place your listener on the element itself.

Comment: Nice but it does not handle the following cases:
- mouse down on the outside and mouse up on the modal should not close
- mouse down on the modal and mouse up on the outside should not close

Answer (score 9):

This is working for me:
I have an image inside of the modal window, so if someone click outside the image (centered):

**html code:**

```
<div id="modal_div"><img id="image_in_modal_div" src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

**ccs code:**

```css
#modal_div {
        display: none;
          position: fixed; 
        z-index: 1; 
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        overflow: auto; 
          background-color: transparent;
}

#image_in_modal_div {
       left: 50%;
       top: 30%;
       position: absolute;
}
```

**mixed jquery and javascript code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#element_that_opens_modal").click(function(){
        $("#modal_div").show();
    });

    window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target.id != "image_in_modal_div") {
          $("#modal_div").hide();
       }
    }

});
```

Comment: This worked nicely for me, although I see that `event` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
var images_modal = document.getElementById('images-model-div');

var videos_modal = document.getElementById('video-model-div');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.onclick = function(event) {

   if (event.target == images_modal) {

      images_modal.style.display = "none";

    }

    if (event.target == videos_modal) {

      videos_modal.style.display = "none";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the most efficient way, but it will work. The idea is to traverse the tree and check if the parent is the id of the one where you don't want to hide on click anywhere except it.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {    
    var p = e.target;
    while(p) {
        console.log(p);
        if(p.id) {
            if(p.id == 'openModal') {
                return;
            }
        }
        p = p.parentElement;
    }
    $("#openModal").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.modal-open', function(e) {
    
    $('.modal-background, .modal').show();
    e.preventDefault();
})
.on('click', '.modal-close', function(e) {
    
    $('.modal-background, .modal').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});

if ( !$('.modal-background.modal-close').length ) {
    $('<div/>').addClass('modal-background modal-close').appendTo('body');
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 15px;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 5% auto 0 -200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.modal-background {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /* background: transparent; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9; /* .modal[zIndex] - 1 */
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<button type="button" class="modal-open">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal">
    <p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="$('.dummy-container').toggle()">Toggle something for testing</button>
    <p>
    <p class="dummy-container" style="display: none;">
        Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" class="modal-close">Close modal</button>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample markup:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="media-modal-wrapper">
    <div class="media-modal">Modal content here...</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A very helpful solution to this problem:

```
    var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('media-modal-wrapper')[0];
    wrapper.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const self = event.target.closest('.media-modal');
    if (!self) {
        wrapper.classList.add('hidden')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my dropup menu that I was coding outside of the bootstrap framework. Basically, if a click was outside the enclosing div, then close the menu.
Use the `Node.contains` method.

```
function checkParent(parent, child) {
    if (parent.contains(child))
        return true;
        return false;
}
```

credit to [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-a-child-of-a-parent-using-javascript/)

Comment: it really helps if you don't want a backdrop for a custom modal/popup!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to put the "outside" (the backdrop/background) **inside** of the wrapper element for the modal parts.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="modal-root" style="display: none;">
  <div id="modal-bg" onclick="onClickModalBackdrop(this)"></div>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal-close-btn" onclick="onClickModalCloseBtn(this)">X</div>
    <!-- content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#modal-root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#modal {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: relative;
}

#modal-close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
  color: #959595;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#modal-close-btn:hover {
  color: #757575;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border-color: #959595;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
function showModal() {
  document.getElementById("modal-root").style.display = '';
}

function onClickModalBackdrop(e) {
  e.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}

function onClickModalCloseBtn(e) {
  e.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}

showModal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code you can add data-backdrop="true" on div modal . its work for me

```
<div class="modalDialog" id="openModal" data-backdrop="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery, hide the element that has the class 'hider'.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  var container = $(".hider");
  if(!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){ container.slideUp(80); }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#bootstrap_modal_id").modal({
    backdrop: true,
});
```